# Nuxt switch Layout by button

Tags: vue.js, layout, switch-statement, nuxt.js

Is it possible to switch the layout dynamically with a button?

I've tried different methods, but none of them worked.

```
data(){
   return {
     layoutName: 'default'
   }
},
layout: this.layoutName
```

and I tried to use Vuex too

```
layout: this.$store.state.layoutName
```

Comment: here is a good discussion about this topic https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3877 havent figured myself yet

Comment: @mangrove108, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out. In Nuxt you can change the layout programmatically by using this method:

```
this.$nuxt.setLayout('Layout_Name')
```

Comment: great i did with nuxt/store works, but will check this out too 